# How to install Thunderbolt?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I usually work with AS3 but at the moment I need to debug an AS2 file in browser.

I heard Thunderbolt is a good extension. But I've read everything on the wiki but found no instructions to installing/implementing it and its driving me insane.

Here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/wiki/ThunderBoltAS2

Can someone please give me some instructions to how to go about adding Thunderbolt to my browser??

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but did you get to [here](http://flash-thunderbolt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as2/)? You'll also need Firebug, as this is an extension for that plugin.

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding the question but to my knowledge most flash IDEs are backwards compatiable to as2. Just install the flash player debugger version. You can also look into flash bug FireFox plug in if that helps

Comment: @The_asMan Hmm I am actually pretty confused. I've tried using Firefox's Flashbug, but when I tried to detect the AS2 file, it says "No AS3 SWF files detected on this page." Is that an Flashbug problem? I thought I HAD to use Thurderbolt. I'm feeling pretty stupid over this whole thing actually. Can you give me some instructions (i.e. any links) to debug AS2 swfs in browser?